# Passing contents of multiplt files to a stored procedure

Tags: powershell

Currently, I'm using this script to read all ID.txt files on my D:\ drive and output a CSV file containing all of the contents.  In each file, there will only ever be a number and it's always on the first line.

```cs
$PATH = "D:\"
$Out = @()

Get-ChildItem $PATH -Filter ID.txt -File -Recurse | foreach {
    $fileData = @{
        "Content" = (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw)
    }
    $Out += (New-Object PSObject -Property $fileData)
}

$Out | Export-Csv "C:\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This has worked for us for quite some time but the goalposts have now moved.

Instead of outputting a CSV file with the ID's, we now want to pass the contents of the ID.txt files directly to a stored procedure as a variable.

The stored procedure accepts the input as `varchar(max)` and is passed to the query as an `IN` statement.

Is it possible to generate a comma separated list and pass it to a stored procedure in one move without creating a file with the values first?

Answer (score 0):

`$Out  -join ","` will format your array as a comma separated string, assuming $out is a 1 dimensional array of the IDs you need.

You may need to use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID` when you `Get-Content` from your file, where ID is the column name, to get a array of just the ID values that you want.